# How to submit form in new pop up on button onclick action

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to have a form and need to submit it to a url in a new pop up window on button onclick action. I want something like this.

```
<form id = "test" name = "test" action = "preview.jsp">
    Email : <input type = "text" name = "email"/>
    <button id = "submitButton" onclick = "submitFormInPopUp()"/>
</form>
```

So how to write this function submitFormInPopUp() which posts to action url in a new pop up page.

Thanks

Jitendra

Comment: how do you want to create a popup? on different window or same window??

Comment: check the answer provided it'll help you

Comment: Thanks all for quick responses. Answers by wong2 and Anand works.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use this:

```
function submitFormInPopUp() 
{
 window.open('','Prvwindow','location=no,status=no,toolbar=no,scrollbars=yes,width=730,height=500');

 document.test.action = "preview.jsp"
 document.test.target = "Prvwindow"
 document.test.submit(); 
}
```

i hope its help to u

Answer (score 0):

```
function submitFormInPopUp(){
    var url = "preview.jsp?email=" + document.getElementsByTagName('input')[0].value;
    window.open(url);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could use the `target` attribute?

http://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/att_form_target.asp

Change the button type to `submit` and specify `target`, you don't need any javascript.

```
<form id="test" name="test" action="preview.jsp" target="_blank">
    Email : <input type = "text" name = "email"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="submitButton" />
</form>
```

Be aware though it's deprecated and not allowed in Strict.

Comment: I didn't want to use input type = "submit" and had to use button.

Comment: For just opening the results of a form POST in a new window/tab, this is a great way of doing so. The comment that it's deprecated is incorrect. It's in HTML5 but was left out of Strict.